# How to select a sum of max 100

Tags: sql, sql-server

I will make a sql statement that retrieves all the images as long as the sum of the size is 100

I have this:

```
SELECT PhotoNr
INTO # PhotoTabl
FROM Photo
WHERE Size <= 100????

ORDER BY PhotoOrder ASC
```

Table-Contents:

```
PhotoNr ...... Size
1 ............ 20
2 ............ 50
3 ............ 20
4 ............ 50
5 ............ 20
```

The sql will give the result:

```
PhotoNr ...... Size
1 ............ 20
2 ............ 50
3 ............ 20
```

Is there any good solution for this?

Comment: looking at your query and result you have it.. not sure what is the problem.. you are not doing sum just curious..

Comment: @AJP - They need to do a running total and only include those rows before it exceeds 100.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  Also how many rows in the table and what indexes are there are on the table? And are you ordering by `PhotoOrder` per the `SELECT` or `PhotoNr` per the example data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways to skin this cat. The best will depend on what's available to you, and the limitations imposed by size etc

One option would be to use a recursive CTE (this simple example assumes consecutive photonr values, non-consecutive could be allowed for if required):

```
;WITH CTE as (
  select PhotoNr, Size, Tot = Size
  from photos where photonr = 1
  union all
  select p.PhotoNr, p.Size, Tot = cte.Tot +p.Size
  from CTE
  join photos p on CTE.PhotoNr + 1 = p.photonr
  )
select photonr, size from cte
where tot < 100
```

[SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ff4b/5/0A)

Alternatively a very simple way (to code) (but may not be so performant) could use `cross apply`:

```
select
  photonr,
  size
from photos p
  cross apply (
    select tot = sum(size) from photos sub
    where sub.photonr <= p.photonr) x
where tot <= 100
```

[Another SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ff4b/13)

Comment: You're also assuming `PhotoNr` is contiguous.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on SQL Server 2012+, there is an index with key column `PhotoNr` that includes `Size` and the number of rows expected to be returned is small relative to the number of rows in the table.

```
WITH P
     AS (SELECT *,
                SUM(Size) OVER (ORDER BY PhotoNr  
                                ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS RunningCount
         FROM   Photo)
SELECT *
FROM   Photo
WHERE  PhotoNr < (SELECT TOP 1 PhotoNr
                  FROM   P
                  WHERE  RunningCount > 100
                  ORDER  BY PhotoNr)
```

Comment: Why the complex bit after the CTE is built? - at that point just `SELECT PhotoNr,Size from p where runningcount <= 100` will get the results

Comment: @JonEgerton - So it can stop processing any more rows after that. Whether this is worthwhile depends on the proportion of the table that is expected to be returned.

Comment: When i try this, i get "Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS'." Is the web hosts sql server to old? (MSSQL 10.50.1600.1)

Comment: @user784253 yes. That is 2008 R2. That syntax requires 2012+

Answer (score 0):

As `@MartinSmith` has said in the comments you just need to calculate a running total. There are many ways and it depends on you RDBMS as to what you can leverage to improve efficiency etc. One basic but pretty inefficient way is like this.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT p1.id, p1.size, SUM(p2.size) running_total
    FROM photos p1, photos p2
    WHERE p1.id >= p2.id
    GROUP BY p1.id, p1.size
)

SELECT id, size
FROM cte 
WHERE running_total <= 100
```

There is an interesting looking article comparing methods for creating a running total [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals)

Comment: If the table is large this will perform badly.